# How to debug JavaScript code executed inside Microsoft Teams tab?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am developing a Microsoft Teams app. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/general/debug) does not mention how to debug the actual JS code running inside the teams app.

For other office 365 add-ins based on Office JS like outlook, word etc. we can use F12 tool to debug the JavaScript. I am looking for a similar experience for teams addin.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can debug native team’s client without any configurations by enabling developer tools on teams. To enable developer mode click 7 times on the team’s status icon as shown below.
[image: Screenshot]
Once the developer mode enabled, right click on it and you can see two main options open DevTools (Main Window) and Open DevTools (All WebContents) to debug the team applications.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Microsoft fails to mention the clicking 7 times.

Comment: any idea how to do this for Mac OS?

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS, to access developer tools, you first have to enter developer preview mode. Click the three dots at the upper right corner, next to your profile, select `About`, then click `Developer preview`.

[image]

Then right click Microsoft Teams in the dock and select `Open DevTools`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is also documented here now:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools#access-devtools-on-the-desktop